# why this.state is showing empty in messageParser

Tags: reactjs

I'm using a `react-chatbot-kit` module , at the `console.log("calling getcong",getConfig())` i can see that data is set to the state , but in messageParser when i tried to check with `console.log("state data", this.state)` is showing empty . i dont know what i'm doing wrong here please hepl me thanks in advance...

this is the logs of `console.log("calling getcong",getConfig())` :
[image]

this is the `console.log("state data", this.state)`:[image]
questions is showing empty

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Chatbot from "react-chatbot-kit";
import axios from 'axios';
import { createChatBotMessage } from "react-chatbot-kit";

import MessageParser from "./MessageParser";
import ActionProvider from "./ActionProvider";

function App() {
 const [getQuestion, setQuestion] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
   axios
   .get("********************")
   .then(response => {
     setQuestion(response.data.question)
    })
   }
 ,[])
  
   const getConfig = () => {
     var state = {
      questions:getQuestion
     }
     return {
     initialMessages: [
      createChatBotMessage(
       `Hi I’m here to help you with self-assesment.`
      )]
     state: state,
    }
  }

console.log("calling getcong",getConfig())

return (
  <div className="App">
   <Chatbot
    config={getConfig()}    
    messageParser={MessageParser}
    actionProvider={ActionProvider}
    placeholderText="Customer Message Here"
   />
 </div>
 );
}

export default App;
```

messageParser file:

```
class MessageParser {
   constructor(actionProvider, state) {
    this.actionProvider = actionProvider;
    this.state = state
 }

parse = (message) => {
console.log('current message' + message);
console.log("state data", this.state);
}

export default MessageParser;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your MessageParser class has to extend from React.Component. Only then you can access the state and render methods

```js
class MessageParser extends React.Component {
   state = {}
   constructor(actionProvider, props) {
    this.actionProvider = actionProvider;
    super(props)
   }
   render(){return<></>}

   parse = (message) => {
   console.log('current message' + message);
   console.log("state data", this.state);
}

export default MessageParser;
```